# Azure, Web Service: "no filtering" choice

Tags: sql, azure, filtering, azure-machine-learning-service

I have designed a little experiment on AzureML.
Suppose my dataset has *column1* (A, B, C are the "unique" elements) and *column2* (D, E, F are the unique elements).

In the way shown in picture I am able to take as input to the "Execute R Script" module the whole dataset with both the columns (port 1) and make a filtering with the parameters passed in the port 2. In this way, when I create the Web Service and I have to insert the values for the *column1* it automatically creates a picklist with the values "A", "B" and "C". So the user cannot choose a value different from them, and I like it!

Now, I want another obvious choice too: I want the user having the possibility to choose "no filtering" as fourth option (such that no filtering is done on the column1). There exists an easy way to force Azure to give this possibility?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create additional port to pass no filtering option, then try using custom module which allows you to define more than two ports.

BTW - you can also have multiple web service inputs and multiple web service outputs.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-custom-r-modules/